# Disqus comments in drupal Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, disqus

I have a Drupal view created (a block level view) in which I need to display the Disqus comment block.

The view displays movie reviews and each review node has a related comment block, but im not sure how to display that block in the view. (The block displays when you go to each node page specifically.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

place the Disqus comment block after the view.